# Extjs 4.1.0 grid store fields appending with Id

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a grid panel with JSON store, if I give alert (myGrid.model.prototype.fields.keys), it is showing all fields name ending with `id`, for example if I have two fields `a1`, `a2`, in alert it is showing as ('a1','a2','id'). I don't know how this Id is getting appended to the fields. If I do the same in extjs4.0.2, it's working fine, but with extjs 4.1.0 it's showing this problem.

Sample code is:

```
 tbar : [{
          text : 'Save',
          height : 20,
          handler : function(){
            var gridColumnIds = component.gridStore1.model.prototype.fields.keys;

            // alert(grid1.columns[0].dataIndex)
            // console.log(gridColumnIds);
            alert("grid ids :"+gridColumnIds);
            var gridData = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(component.gridStore1.data.items,'data'));
            alert("grid data is :"+gridData);
          }
         },{
          text : 'Get Record',
          height : 20,
          handler : function(){
            p1.show();
          }
         }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's caused because you used Model with default idProperty value (idProperty == 'id' by default). Try change this property http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty.

Comment: thanks 4 ur response, may i knw how to remove that idProperty. I dnt want that id. I just want wat r all the field names present